# Extracting text into a new column after \n new line

Tags: r

I am trying to map over a list and create a new column which extracts from the `financialVariable` column the text/currency symbol after the `\n` line break. I tried using the following `map(., ~mutate(currency = str_extract(., "\n")))` which give an error.

The data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable  `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`   
  <chr>              <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 "Ventas Cliente"   98716127 1477902   1970536   2955805   4433708  
2 "Revenue\n€"       987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,708
3 "Expenditure\n€"   890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,434
4 "Profit (Loss)\n€" 96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274  

$company11
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable    `2019`   `2020`   `2021`    `2022`    `2023`   
  <chr>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 "B2C and B2B Sales"  2        2        2         2         2        
2 "Revenue\nCHF"       69,000   170,000  506,000   1,269,000 3,110,000
3 "Expenditure\nCHF"   187,000  556,000  1,102,000 2,013,000 3,761,000
4 "Profit (Loss)\nCHF" -118,000 -386,000 -596,000  -744,000  -651,000 

$company7
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable  `2019` `2020`
  <chr>              <chr>  <chr> 
1 "0"                0      0     
2 "Revenue\n£"       0      0     
3 "Expenditure\n£"   0      0     
4 "Profit (Loss)\n£" 0      0
```

So I want to have a new column `currency` which contains the €, CHF or £.

Data:

```
list(company1 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("Ventas Cliente", 
"Revenue\n\200", "Expenditure\n\200", "Profit (Loss)\n\200"), 
    `2019` = c("98716127", "987,161", "890,623", "96,538"), `2020` = c("1477902", 
    "1,477,902", "1,337,031", "140,871"), `2021` = c("1970536", 
    "1,970,536", "1,732,873", "237,663"), `2022` = c("2955805", 
    "2,955,805", "2,569,122", "386,683"), `2023` = c("4433708", 
    "4,433,708", "3,829,434", "604,274")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("Expenditure\n\200", 
"Profit (Loss)\n\200", "Revenue\n\200", "Ventas Cliente"), .rows = structure(list(
    3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), company11 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("B2C and B2B Sales", 
"Revenue\nCHF", "Expenditure\nCHF", "Profit (Loss)\nCHF"), `2019` = c("2", 
"69,000", "187,000", "-118,000"), `2020` = c("2", "170,000", 
"556,000", "-386,000"), `2021` = c("2", "506,000", "1,102,000", 
"-596,000"), `2022` = c("2", "1,269,000", "2,013,000", "-744,000"
), `2023` = c("2", "3,110,000", "3,761,000", "-651,000")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("B2C and B2B Sales", 
"Expenditure\nCHF", "Profit (Loss)\nCHF", "Revenue\nCHF"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), company7 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("0", 
"Revenue\n£", "Expenditure\n£", "Profit (Loss)\n£"), `2019` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0"), `2020` = c("0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("0", "Expenditure\n£", 
"Profit (Loss)\n£", "Revenue\n£"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: See `?tidyr::separate`

Comment: This seemed to work `myList %>%  map(.,  ~separate(.x, financialVariable, into = c("financialVariable", "Currency"), "\n"))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed three things:

a) you also want to give back the dataframe from map if you use mutate

b) you want to split the column `financialVariable`

c) you may need more escape slashes before the `n`

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% map(., function(x){
  x %>% 
    mutate(currency = str_split(.$financialVariable,"\\\n")[[2]][2])
})
$company1
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable     `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    currency
  <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
1 "Ventas Cliente"      98716127 1477902   1970536   2955805   4433708   "\x80"  
2 "Revenue\n\x80"       987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,708 "\x80"  
3 "Expenditure\n\x80"   890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,434 "\x80"  
4 "Profit (Loss)\n\x80" 96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274   "\x80"  

$company11
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable    `2019`   `2020`   `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    currency
  <chr>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
1 "B2C and B2B Sales"  2        2        2         2         2         CHF     
2 "Revenue\nCHF"       69,000   170,000  506,000   1,269,000 3,110,000 CHF     
3 "Expenditure\nCHF"   187,000  556,000  1,102,000 2,013,000 3,761,000 CHF     
4 "Profit (Loss)\nCHF" -118,000 -386,000 -596,000  -744,000  -651,000  CHF     

$company7
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable  `2019` `2020` currency
  <chr>              <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 "0"                0      0      £       
2 "Revenue\n£"       0      0      £       
3 "Expenditure\n£"   0      0      £       
4 "Profit (Loss)\n£" 0      0      £
```

Answer (score 1):

If `cmp` is your list:

```r
cmp %>% map(~.x %>% 
               mutate(currency = 
                         sub("^(.*)\\n(.*)$","\\2", 
                              financialVariable, 
                              perl = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)))
$company1
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable     `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    currency      
  <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         
1 "Ventas Cliente"      98716127 1477902   1970536   2955805   4433708   Ventas Cliente
2 "Revenue\n\x80"       987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,708 \x80          
3 "Expenditure\n\x80"   890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,434 \x80          
4 "Profit (Loss)\n\x80" 96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274   \x80          

$company11
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable    `2019`   `2020`   `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    currency         
  <chr>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>            
1 "B2C and B2B Sales"  2        2        2         2         2         B2C and B2B Sales
2 "Revenue\nCHF"       69,000   170,000  506,000   1,269,000 3,110,000 CHF              
3 "Expenditure\nCHF"   187,000  556,000  1,102,000 2,013,000 3,761,000 CHF              
4 "Profit (Loss)\nCHF" -118,000 -386,000 -596,000  -744,000  -651,000  CHF              

$company7
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   financialVariable [4]
  financialVariable  `2019` `2020` currency
  <chr>              <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 "0"                0      0      0       
2 "Revenue\n£"       0      0      £       
3 "Expenditure\n£"   0      0      £       
4 "Profit (Loss)\n£" 0      0      £
```